# How to apply a Ribbon to a custom List Definition

Tags: ribbon, custom-list

I have a custom list definition defined as follow:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List Definition project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
  <ListTemplate
    Name="Faldone Cliente"
    Type="10001"
    BaseType="1"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="110"
    DisplayName="Faldone Cliente"
    Description="Struttura per la gestione del faldone cliente."
    Image="/_layouts/images/CONTACTS.png"
    FolderCreation ="FALSE"
    VersioningEnabled="TRUE"
    DisallowContentTypes="FALSE"
    Category="Libraries"
    MultipleTypes="TRUE"
    />
</Elements>
```

And a Ribbon defined as:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <CustomAction
 Id="TabCliente"
 Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
 RegistrationId="101"
RegistrationType="List"
 >
```

This works with every document library but not with my custom list (can't see it at all)

How can I make my Ribbon visible only on my custom list definition??

There is a way to link the ribbon on my ID? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do that!

By code debugging i found the Template ID of my List. This was 10001, so I put it in the ribbon instead of 101 and magically the Ribbon appears ;-)